# Weather Report song title "Dara Factor One" – What is “Dara Factor”?

Tags: jazz, song-title

What does the music title "Dara Factor" means of the song "Dara Factor One" by  *Weather Report* ?

I would like to know the meaning of the song title "Dara Factor".

URL for this music:

Comment: There's another track on the same album called "Dara Factor Two¨. That explains the "One" part.

Answer (score 4):

This detailed website [Weather Report: the annotated discography](https://www.weatherreportdiscography.org/weather-report-1982/) describes the two Dara songs like this - both quotes are from Brian Glasser's "In a Silent Way" (shortened to IASW below),  Sanctuary Publishing Limited, 2001.

> " Erskine explained the genesis of “Dara Factor One” and “Dara Factor
>   Two” to Brian Glasser: “The Dara Factors–that was one long jam. I
>   remember they got this extra-large reel of tape, and when we were
>   doing it they even ran a speaker out into the lounge so all the people
>   working in the studio could hear it. We wanted to do a jam, and at one
>   point I said, ‘Joe, how about something like this? This would be fun,’
>   and I played a kind of pocket groove. I thought it was cool. And Joe
>   waved me to stop. He’s standing in the center of the room, I’m in my
>   drum booth, and he says through the microphones, ‘What’s fun about
>   that? I don’t hear anything fun in that.’ So that’s why Dara had that
>   kind of ass-backwards beat, because he was always looking for
>   something out of the ordinary.” [IASW, p. 226]
>
> Brian Risner told Glasser, “Dara Factor was basically, ‘Hey, we got an
>   hour left. What are we gonna do?’ And I was so efficient with the
>   production on that record–we had two days booked, and we’d gone in and
>   gotten two takes on everything, maybe three, and we’d gotten
>   everything we wanted. So he had an interesting sequence pattern,
>   probably on the Oberheim, and they jammed on that. There was a lot of
>   work on post [-production] on it, because basically it was a groove
>   and a basic melody, so we cut it and added a lot of the accents and
>   stuff to make it work.” [IASW, p. 226]"

I can find no references to "Dara" as a fictional character or film, or brand name, other than references to the Weather report tunes, or folk with the first name "Dara".
So, in keeping with the song's origin as a way to fill up a recording tape, I'd say the title is equally ad-hoc and has no particular meaning.

"Dara factor"  sounds to me like the kind of thing (effect, product, sinister organisation) that would belong in some sci-fi or comic book/cartoon universe :  so maybe there was the intention to give the track a  mysterious name, in keeping with the band's avant-garde image and status,  but that is really just my own opinion, based on no hard evidence.  Compare with their other quirky titles "Mysterious traveller" etc.

Answer (score 3):

Great News --- Obtained the answer from (Weather Report drummer) Peter Erskine himself ----

> “Dara” was a made-up word for something in the band, I don’t remember what exactly … Jaco, and then Joe, liked to add the word “factor” to another word, as if to explain a phenomenon or event … so, the “Dara Factor” is an inside joke, linguistically, without any real meaning. That’s my best recounting
> -Peter Erskine

Comment: Did you reach out to him directly, or did you find this quote somewhere (if so, please cite your source).